# Getting market error "Sorry there's not enough space to install this item."

Tags: 2.2-froyo, google-play-store, internal-storage

Android Froyo 2.2 with 3GB available mmcblk0p2 space and over 3GB free space on MicroSD.

Have no idea from when it started. Since then, every time when I try to download/update an APP from Android Market, it prompted the "Sorry, There's not enough space to install this item." message for further action.

Have tried a few hints from Web, but yet no luck:

- Format MicroSD.
- Clean up Memory and Cache of Android Market.
- Repartition the main storage from 4GB to 3GB.
- tune2fs -m 1 /dev/block/mmcblk0p2

Any body can give steps to overcome this?

---Update on Debug message gathered from ADB---

When I clicked on Install-->OK to start download from Market, it logged a warning message in logcat:

> 14:45:16.928 Warning PackageManager 1948  Couldn't clear application caches

---Storage Structures---

```
#df -ha

Filesystem               Size    Used    Available    Use%    Mounted on
/dev/root                2.9G    652.8M   2.2G         22%     /
tmpfs                   76.8M     12.0K  76.8M          0%     /dev
tmpfs                   76.8M      0     76.8M          0%     /mnt/asec
tmpfs                    4.0M      0      4.0M          0%     /sqlite_stmt_journals
/dev/block/vold/179:9    3.7G     41.2M   3.6G          1%     /mnt/sdcard
/dev/block/vold/179:9    3.7G     41.2M   3.6G          1%     /mnt/secure/asec
tmpfs                    0         0      0             0%     /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure
```

## ====== Update on 2nd Aug 2011 ======

**
After days of research, found a few discussion about the error of calculation on available space in Android 2.2 series.  Someone was mentioned on the maximum partition size which might caused this problem.  Thus I have run a test on this, to repartitioned the system partition from 3GB down to 2GB and the market was back to normal...
Any idea on how to solve this?**

Comment: Application caches and data mounts are probably low on space.

Comment: Which device are you using? Sometimes that matters

Comment: Can you show us the "normal" space information?  From `Settings -> SD card and phone storage`.

Comment: @Ray, There are over 3GB available space on both Machine Memory and MicroSD.  Believed Low on Space is not an issue.

Comment: @Broam,
I am using the porting version of O2Droid.  Previously was used with no problem.  Until a day it appears system corrupted, after reinstall the whole system, it happens.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because my Gingerbread update was filling the /cache folder.  Deleted it (this probably requires root) and was able to update apps again.

Comment: Depending on your bootloader, `fastboot erase cache` may work. You don't need to have an engineering bootloader; later "ship" loaders allow for this too.